# JavaFX - How to use shift click on CheckBoxListCell.forListView

Tags: java, javafx, checkboxlist, shift

I'm working on a project in JavaFX and I'm trying to enable multi-selection of checkboxes inside a ListView with this code:

```
    ListView<ActivableItem> listView = new ListView<>();
    listView.setPrefSize(210, 210);
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    listView.setCellFactory(
        CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<ActivableItem, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(ActivableItem item) {
            return item.getBooleanProperty();
        }
    }));
    // filling listView and making other stuff
```

Where ActivableItem is a class I made containing an item (generic type) and a BooleanProperty attributes.

As a result, I have a correct ListView with checkable items

[ListView checkable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeT7p.png)

Shift + click works well on cells, I can select them, but checkboxes do not seem to understand the SelectionMode.MULTIPLE property. Instead, when I use shift click on a checkbox, the cell is not even checked, it is on a focus mode (like in the image)

For now, I'm working on alternate solutions (select cells, click on button "check" or create my own cell factory), but it would be more convenient if I could use what is already made, so...

Is it possible ? Is there a way to enable multi selection of check boxes ?

I'm seeking for help, Thanks.

Comment: By default, you should be able to check multiple check boxes just by clicking (not shift-clicking) on them. Maybe I don't understand what you want to happen?

Comment: I want to be able to check a serie of checkboxes at once, for instance, the checkbox n° 3 to the checkbox n°60 by using the shift key (instead of clicking one checkbox by one).

Comment: There's no built-in behavior in check box list cell for that. It sounds like you should just be using the list view's built-in selection, instead of a check box anyway...

Comment: Ok, so I think should resolve this with another solution (or an alternate one). Too bad it was not made the way I expected, but thanks for answering.